# How to read data from a Bluethooth BLE device without pair in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth device and I need to read data from it but without pairing with it, since it does not allow it, but I do not know how to do it, I know it is possible because I have another application that does it, but I do not know how to display the device data.

Thank you

Comment: BLE does not require pairing. However a device can require that certain characteristics require pairing/encryption. If you say that another application can do it without pairing, then it seems you should be able to communicate with it as well with no issues. Please follow some guides/tutorials, and if you have some code that does not work, feel free to post it and tell exactly what doesn't work with it / which errors you get etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth works by pairing with a specific device, whereas BLE is more like a community message board, with devices posting little pieces of information or accepting small updates. Take a look at the official Android docs on BLE. They describe the basics of the protocol and outline how to discover devices and perform read/write operations: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le